# Difference-in-Difference model with multiple treatment groups

Tags: r, interaction, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, control-group

I am currently investigating the effect of the implementation of eco-labels on unit sales with a difference-in-difference estimation. I have a variable period indicating the pre- and post-period, a variable label indicating whether the product is labelled or not, some control variables and the variable lr which contains the different stars of the labels ranging from one to five and a control group called control. A product can contain 0 to 5 stars indicating the sustainability of the product, 0 being the worst and 5 being the best. However, for my main effect I estimated the effect between labelled * period. Now, I want to know whether this effect is strengthened or not by the number of stars on the label. The variables labelled and lr are correlated as all the unlabelled products are part of the control group. How do I estimate using a difference in difference model the moderating effect of the number of labels on the interaction? Currently I am using R as coding programme so any advice for a code in R would be helpful!